# Fourier transform of exponent

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I need to count the Fourier transform of the following function but it does not seem so obvious for me.

$f(x)=(e^{-ab})-1$ for $x\ge0$ and 
$f(x)=0$ for $x<0$

where: 
$a=1$ and $b=-1$

I don't know whether I should use the standard method or is there any other efficient way?

Comment: what do you mean by "count"? f(0)=? did you miss an x or is the function constant on these two intervalls?

Comment: I do not really get your comment. What have I written wrong for you?

Comment: "to count the Fourier transform" what does this mean? And $f$ is not defined in 0 you say?

Comment: Well, you could understand it like that, but I was  meant to designate the after transformation function let's say $f(k)$

Comment: ok :) I wasn't aware of the word "count" in the context of "calculate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original post has $f$ defined such that

$$f(x)=(e^{-ab}-1)H(x)$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside function defined as

$$H(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\ge 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

The Fourier-Transform $\hat H(k)$ of the Heaviside function is

$$\hat H(k)\equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x)e^{ikx}dx=\pi \delta(k)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{k}\right)$$

where PV denotes the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta and is a [Generalized function or Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions) defined as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$$

for all test functions $f$.

Thus, we have for $a=1$ and $b=-1$ (as in the original post)

$$\hat f(k)=(e-1)\left(\pi \delta(k)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{k}\right)\right)$$

Comment: It does not really helps me. The function did not contain the Heaviside function at all. It probably was a mistake made by me caused of lack of MathJax knowledge. The function looks like it should now.

Comment: The Heaviside function is $1$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$.  $f$ is just a multiple of the Heaviside function.

Comment: Ah, right. I would be grateful for explaining the following symbols :) It helped me a lot anyway

Comment: @Beginnerinfort Which symbols?

Comment: $\delta(k)$ and ${PV}$